# Align form using table in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wanna align form in a table in codeigniter. when I try to do align using HTML below code. it threw error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Page</title>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>Login!</h1>

        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <?php 
        echo form_open('main/login_validation');
        <table>     
        <tr>
        <td>echo "<p> Email : "; </td>
        <td>echo form_input('email',$this->input->post('email')); </td>
        //echo "</p>";
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>echo "<p> Password : ";</td>
        <td>echo form_password('password');</td>
        //echo "</p>";
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>echo "<p>";</td>
        <td>echo form_submit('login_submit','Login');</td>
        //echo "</p>";
        </tr>

        <table>

        echo form_close();


        ?>

        <a href='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/main/signup";?>'> Sign Up </a>

                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\jobsite\application\views\login.php on line 18** I wish to know one more thing that I way I did is correct or wrong?

Comment: if you got an error in your 18th line check the line before. the error is an   end PHP tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags are still open when you switch to HTML output, you need to close the PHP tag each time... try something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Page</title>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>Login!</h1>

        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <?php echo form_open('main/login_validation'); ?>
        <table>     
        <tr>
        <td><p>Email :</p></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email',$this->input->post('email')); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><p>Password :</p></td>
        <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('login_submit','Login'); ?></td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

        <a href='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/main/signup";?>'> Sign Up </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unclosed `php` tag on line 17

```
  echo form_open('main/login_validation'); ?>
```

In fact, you have several unclosed tags there, check